# how to loop through ALL the attributes and return the values as objects

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function  that takes in a argument which is a list of elements. The elements are all `labels` and `inputs`.The function should create an object where the text of the `labels` are the keys of the object and the values of the `inputs` are the values belonging to the keys of the object.I need my function must return this object.

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('form *') //Selects all children of the form element
formObj(elements)

//I need it to return: {name: "Harry, email: "harry@gmail.com", age: 22}
```

```
<form>
    <label for='name'>name<label/>
    <input type='text' id='name' value="Harry"/>

    <label for='email'>email<label/>
    <input type='email' id='email' value="harry@gmail.com"/>

    <label for='age'>age<label/>
    <input type='text' id='age' value="22"/>
<form/>
```

I have tried to loop through ALL the attributes but am unsure how to go about doing it

Please help out

Comment: please show what you tried and explain what goes wrong with it, then we can help you fix it

Comment: What have you tried? Post minimal code illustrating your attempts.

Comment: Also, your HTML syntax is invalid -- what is `<tagname/>`?!

Comment: Depending on what you'll do with the resulting object, bulltin FormData https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData can help.

Comment: @amm Please explain where do you see <tagname/>?

Comment: @muhammad Fairly certain that @amn is referring to `<label/>` which should be `</label>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through all the elements in `elements` using a `for...of` loop. You can also create an empty array called `form_details`, which will hold your resulting object. For each element, you can get its `id` and `value`. Then, using an `if` statement, you can check whether the `id` and `value` are defined, and if they are, add them as a key-value pair to your object.

See example below:

```js
function formObj(elems) {
  const form_details = {};
  for(let elem of elems) {
    const key = elem.id;
    const val = elem.value;
    if(key && val)
      form_details[key] = val;
  }
  return form_details;
}

const elements = document.querySelectorAll('form *') //Selects all children of the form element

const details = formObj(elements);
console.log(details);
```

```html
<form>
    <label for='name'>name</label>
    <input type='text' id='name' value="Harry"/>

    <label for='email'>email</label>
    <input type='email' id='email' value="harry@gmail.com"/>

    <label for='age'>age</label>
    <input type='text' id='age' value="22"/>
<form/>
```

An easier way would be to change your selector to get the `form` element, and add the `name` attribute to each attribute which you want to retrieve. You can then use the `FormData` Web API to retrieve the entries from your FormData, which you can then turn into an object using `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
function formObj(elem) {
  const form = new FormData(elem);
  return Object.fromEntries([...form.entries()]);
}

const elements = document.querySelector('form') //Selects all children of the form element

const details = formObj(elements);
console.log(details);
```

```html
<form>
    <label for='name'>name</label>
    <input type='text' name='name' id='name' value="Harry"/>

    <label for='email'>email</label>
    <input type='email' name='email' id='email' value="harry@gmail.com"/>

    <label for='age'>age</label>
    <input type='text' name='age' id='age' value="22"/>
<form/>
```

Comment: What if `age` is `0`? Oh wait, then the value is `"0"`, which is truthy...

Comment: The person asking the question ask for keys to be the *text* of the labels, not their name. Anyway, the question is far too unclear to jump at writing answers, so proceed at own risk.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the children of the form that are of type `input` and also have an `id` and for each one add the a property to an object.

```js
function getCustomFormData(form) {
  return [].reduce.call(form.querySelectorAll("input[id]"), function(result, dom) {
    return result[dom.id] = dom.value, result;
  }, {});
}

var form = document.querySelector("form");
var data = getCustomFormData(form);
console.log(data);
```

```html
<form>
    <label for='name'>name</label>
    <input type='text' id='name' value="Harry">
    <label for='email'>email</label>
    <input type='email' id='email' value="harry@gmail.com">
    <label for='age'>age</label>
    <input type='text' id='age' value="22">
<form/>
```

If your data were of the following form (use the `name` in the same way you are using the `id` attribute) you could use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) instead

```js
function getCustomFormData(form) {
  var result = {};
  new FormData(form).forEach(function(value, key) {
    result[key] = value;
  });
  return result;
}

var form = document.querySelector("form");
var data = getCustomFormData(form);
console.log(data);
```

```html
<form>
  <label for='name'>name</label>
    <input type='text' id='name' name='name' value="Harry">
    <label for='email'>email</label>
    <input type='email' id='email' name='email' value="harry@gmail.com">
    <label for='age'>age</label>
    <input type='text' id='age' name='age' value="22">
<form/>
```